How to design an analog filter for an acoustic sensor
It's been a while since I've done this, but I have an acoustic sensor meant to detect low frequency sound waves attached to a 5/32" ID hose that leads out to open air. I seem to recall from my grad school days that there's a relationship between the length of the hose and the effective pass band (low- or high-pass, I don't recall) of the air column leading to the sensor, but I can't find references online.
I'm looking for that relationship. Basically what length hose do I need if I want a cutoff frequency of, e.g., 20 Hz? 50 Hz? Or more generally what is the equation? Or am I just misremembering, in which case I'll delete the post.

You are looking at the organ pipe resonance, in which the maximum sensitivity will be when the length of the hose is 1/4 of a wavelength. However it will also respond to other frequencies, particularly 3/4 5/4 and so on. c (m/s)=L (m)*f(Hz). c=300 m/s, f=50 hence wavelength at 50 Hz is 6m, you need a 1.5m tube.
If you want a low pass filter you need to use an expansion box. That is small pipe ->big pipe-> small pipe, where the length of the big pipe determines the cutoff frequency, and the ratio of areas determines the attenuation.
